# How do I write xpath for the node below?

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

```
<li class="nav-tab" data-li-name="System" data-url="" data-name="System">

<a class="nav_item" data-name="System" href="javascript:;">

    <i class="nav-top-icon customicon icon-settings"></i>
    <span class="nav_item_text">System</span>

</a>
```

I tried with the below options but no luck. I got the error in the image.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));             
Actions action = new Actions(driver);   
      
IWebElement element=wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//span[@class='nav_item_text' and text()='System']")));
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='nav_item_text' and text()='System']"))).Build().Perform();    
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='nav_item_text' and text()='System")).Click();
```

Tried xpath below one as well but no luck
//a[@class='nav_item'][contains(.,'System')])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpFDG.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a simpler locator here - you have that `data-name="System"` attribute which you could base your locator on instead of going deeper into the tree to check the text of the inner element:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a.nav_item[data-name=System]"))
```

Or, if you insist on using XPath:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@data-name = 'System']"))
```